# Associating human tasks with a bugfix branch

Tags: java, deployment, devops

I am working on a bugfix in a branch, however, the bugfix won't work in production until a large amount of data has been deleted from our database.

I have therefore added a unit test to the branch:

```
/**
 * Before deploying this branch into production, the following data needs to be
 * deleted from such and such a table. 
 * 
 * With a detailed explanation of what needs to happen and so-on.
 */
@Test
public void humanTaskTest() {
    org.junit.Assert.fail("Before deploying this branch please perform the actions described in the Javadoc comment to this test");
}
```

Is there a better way to associate this kind of reminder with a particular branch?

Comment: A more robust way would be an SQL changeset (Liquibase, Flyway) that performs the db operations when the code gets deployed, but if it requires a lot of time or extensive preparations it might be easier to perform that "out of band".

Comment: Yes, it's just there's a huge amount of obsolete data that we need to delete. The fix actually performs this deletion every time data is added but I don't want that initial run to fall over because it's got so much old stuff to remove. I'd rather remove it manually.